# Insert taglist Component inside search result rendering variant

Tags: sxa, components

Can `taglist` component be used inside search result rendering variant?

I tried to use it with in search result rendering and it is just keep spinning and not showing any results. In the `console`, I am seeing "`Value cannot be null. parameter name: database`". I am using sitecore 9.1.1 with Sitecore `SXA` 1.8.1.

Thanks for in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please take the bellow approach as this is working quite fine for me (I've just checked it). I have a couple of pages which I've tagged with three tags:

[image]

Modify your Search Results rendering variant and add Variant Reference item and use `SxaTags` field to pass through:

[image]

Under Variant Reference drop a variant field which will display Title of a tag item:

[image]

Here are the results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Dawid. I am aware of this approach, but I am looking to make the tag behave like taglist. If tag is clicked, I want to display results in assigned search result page. Thanks again :)

Comment: That is easy to achieve! Just add Filter Checliks rendering to those I've on a page you will be able to filter results. Just remember to create a facet and point it to `sxatags` field.